# javascript - google places API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I'm blind and using the google places JavaScript API.
I've created a basic web app to help me search for and see what's near to an address and to find out about local places. 
It plots the points on the map but also lists them on the page by distance and prominance using the nearby search.

Once you click on the find places button, it will list the list of nearby places. If you click on a place name then it should display the place details underneath it like address, phone, reviews etc. 
I am saving the place ID for each place in a button and when you click on it, it passes that to the Display individual place details function.

It doesn't seem to be passing the place_ID to the DisplayIndividualPlaceDetails function. The page can be viewed here:
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adeel786

I think the error is around the line where it says:

```
alert("view individual place details " + objButton.value);
```

as I'm getting an undefined value for that.

The place ID is passed on when I run it on my local computer but it is saved with a .hta extension. If I change the file extension from '.hta' to '.htm' then it won't work in either Internet Explorer on my local machine or online.

Comment: You have a couple syntax errors in your HTML which might not be helping with when you try it as a .htm file: `<div id="gmap_radiusDiv" class="button" display: block">` should be `<div id="gmap_radiusDiv" class="button" style="display: block">`.  And `<button id="button1" class="button" tabindex="0 role="button"` should be `<button id="button1" class="button" tabindex="0" role="button"`

Comment: You might have a problem wherever you create a LatLng, like `var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);`, where the values for lat and lng are coming from `document.getElementById('lat').value`.  This is a text string, but the LatLng constructor expects a floating point number.  You need to specifically cast it to that type: `var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));`

Comment: Thanks Duncan :) I've made the changes you listed and also run the webpage through a HTML validator but it's still not passing on the place_id to the Display individual place details function

Comment: It's working now. The problem was with the syntax I was using for a button.